# Minimizing indented row with Smartsheet Python SDK

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

With the Python SDK, setting a Smartsheet row's `expanded` attribute to `False` doesn't seem to work if the `indent` attribute is also set. The row is not minimized.

```
if i in LEVELS or _i in LEVELS or _j in LEVELS:
    row.expanded = False
elif (TEXT[0].split()[0] not in i) and (TEXT[1] not in i):
    row.indent = 1
else:
    row.indent = 2
```

I've set `row.expanded = False` on the `elif` clause to no effect. How would I do this? Or, is it possible to call a function to 'minimize all' through the API?

Answer (score 0):

Row hierarchy shouldn't have any bearing on if the row is expanded or collapsed. This is most likely an issue with your code's logic.

In the code sample you've provided, you are either collapsing the row or indenting it - never both. If the first set of conditions are met, neither of the other else sections will occur.